# why does removeChild in Javascript always removes the last child and not the one it got the id from?

Tags: javascript, dom, removechild

i have four divs with the eventlistener onclick, 
calling a js function which just does the following :

```
this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
```

i expect it to remove the div i clicked on, but it does not.
instead it deletes the last child and changes the id given after to the
id of the removed child (first click, the last child) and by further clicking on the 
other divs counts down the given id to one. removing
the childNodes in the array from the last to the first.

i tried a lot of variants, for example

```
document.getElementById('parentElementName').removeChild(this.gettAttribute('id'));
```

or

```
parent =document.getElementById('parentElementName');

to_be_removed = document.getElementById(this.gettAttribute('id');

parent.removeChild(to_be_removed);
```

or with childNodes // id = 1,2,3,4

```
to_be_removed =document.getElementById('box_content').childNodes[this.getAttribute('id')];

parent =document.getElementById('box_content');
    parent.removeChild(to_be_removed);
```

strange i can successfully change the visibility or the backgroundColor:

```
document.getElementById('box_content').childNodes[this.getAttribute('id')].style.visibility='hidden';
```

or

Comment: Could you post the click handler function?

Comment: I don't understand why your script isn't working.  Could you provide the HTML too?  Here is what I came up with, and it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/dFw5k/

Comment: The question can't be answered unless you post a complete reduced example. Probably `this` is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to remake what you intended, go to http://jsfiddle.net/6YHcv/ to check it out. Is this what you needed?

If you are on IE and use `attachEvent`, `this` in the event handler would probably refer to the global object, not your element. Otherwise I can't tell why your code isn't working.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should improve your answer by adding relevant explanation and code the worked.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few typos in your code.  Your second example should work just fine, I think (see comments):

```
// make sure this is the parent element's ID and not the name, as this suggests.
    parent = document.getElementById('parentElementName'); 

//note the double 't' in getAttribute; also, you are missing an end bracket
    to_be_removed = document.getElementById(this.gettAttribute('id'); 

//looks good
    parent.removeChild(to_be_removed);
```

Check out this example too, though: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/GYpdH/)

It should be as simple as calling the function `this.parentNode.removeChild(this)` after an onclick handler.

Comment: hello bozdoz, thank you very much for your work! i testet your example and it shows the behaviour as i described as my problem. I use mac os x 10.5 and safari Version 5.0.5 (5533.21.1). i copied your code to my local server and it doesn´t change anything. what os and browser you tested the code with, when it worked for you? thank you a lot for future answer.

Comment: why let you take remove function the  param e , when you don´t use it elsewehere?

Comment: I'm on a PC; it works with Chrome, IE9, Safari 5.1, Firefox 5.0